# Local and S3 page are not rendered the same

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vuejs2

I am current working on a static page using Vue 2 and planning to upload it to AWS S3 service.

However, I ran across this weird problem. The local and the S3 version of the same page (same code and everything) were rendered differently.

Note that:
-They were open in the same browser, just different tabs
-They are using the same code

The problem is related to the text, as the S3 version is much smaller (1366px width) but the value of the font-size is different (both version uses the same em value).

Here's the screenshot of the two pages:

This is the property of the local instance of the static page:
[image]

This is the property from the S3 static page:
[image]

Comment: Since this is all client-side code and CSS, S3 is in no way going to change how it renders in the browser. My guess is some CSS or font file or something isn't being served by S3 at all, which is causing the differences in the browser. You need to open your browser's developer console and look for any error messages, and also look in the network tab to see if any files being requested from the browser aren't being served properly from S3.

Comment: I checked the network in devtool. All relevant files are being downloaded successfully. The only file I'm downloading via third party is the font (which was loaded properly), the rest are all locally stored. No error message too or any hint of something wrong. Everything just works, and for some reason their size are completely different.

Comment: Are you sure you have the zoom level set to 100% in your browser, on both sites?

Comment: Holy jesus. That's embarrassing.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Mark B above, the problem is that one of the window (local) has a different zoom level so the code was actually adjusted for a different view. This can be an easy mistake for those who are relatively new to front-end development as the zoom-level in chrome has no sign except for that small magnifying glass in the right corner.